# How to check with jquery if select has options?

Tags: jquery, html

How to check with jquery if select has options and if it doesn't to disable it and show [not items]?

Answer (score 42):

One way to do to it:

```
if ($('#myselect option').length == 0) {
    $('#myselect').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var $select = $('input:select option');
if(!$select.length )
    $select.attr('disabled', true);
```

Or:

```
$('select:not(:has(option))').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: The first one would test how many select elements are on the page... not how many options they have. And I don't think that `input:select` exists. Should be just `select`.

Comment: @FelixKling: that's what you got if you forget a single word!

Comment: Gave +1 for the second version. The first is not disabling the `<select>` element.

Comment: Am I missing something? `:select` is not a jQuery selector, and `input` is finding input elements? What's the favour of what you've got over `$('select option')`?

Comment: The first one is still wrong ;) Just remove it. Think about it: It gets all option elements in the page and if there is none, it disables them... does not make much sense.

Comment: @Felix: So is the second one... it still includes `input:select` ?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, but apart from that (which is an easy fix) it is correct.

Comment: @Felix: Actually it isn't. `$select` references `option` elements instead of the `select` element, and `.attr()` only fires if there are none. EDIT: Or maybe you meant the selector is otherwise correct? (Now that I've read your other comment, that must be what you meant.)

Comment: @patrick: Uh I'm confused now. I meant, the second one is right, apart from `input:select`. The first one is totally screwed up. What did you mean?

Comment: @Felix: You're not confused at all, I am (or was).

Comment: @patrick, @Felix, @Matt: lol :p thanks for the edit. I messed up the first version indeed.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do it is simply use the jQuery **has** function

```
if ($('#myselect').has('option').length == 0) 
{
    // Hide and disable select input here
}
```

For information on the jQuery **has** function see:
https://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 3):

```
select:not(:has(option))
```

is the selector you'd be looking for. You can use it to find the empty select boxes, disable them, and then append an option saying "No option available" or some such message - like so:

```
var noOptions = $('<option/>').html('No options');
$('select:not(:has(option))').attr('disabled',true).append(noOptions);
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/f3myz/

Answer (score 1):

if you have the empty option, then you can:

```
#Allways you must have the empty option
if ($("select#your_class").children().size() == 1) {
  alert("Without options")
  $("select#your_class").hide()
} else {
  alert("With options")
  $("select#your_class").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let baseCategory = $('#base-categories');

if (baseCategory.children().length > 0) {
  let optionCount = baseCategory.children().length;
  console.log("select has " + optionCount + " option ")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="base-categories">
  <option value="0">option 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

I tested this and it worked perfectly, hope it helps:

```
if($("#myselect").html() == ""){
    $("#myselect").html("<option>[not items]</option>");
    $("#myselect").addProp("disabled","disabled");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('select.class>option').size()
```

OR if your select has an id not a class

```
$('select#id>option').size()
```

it will show you how many options inside